# Delete duplicate roles for SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have looked for the codes but I couldn't make the codes work in my SQL server 2017.

I need to create a stored procedure to avoid data duplication from a table and delete all the data duplicated.

I have created this code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE deldupl_LSBU_Staff AS
SELECT Phone_number, COUNT(*) as CNT
FROM LSBU_Staff
GROUP BY Phone_number
DELETE FROM LSBU_Staff  
WHERE Phone_number > 1;
```

BUT when I execute my code, it deletes all the records from the table and I do not want this. I just want to delete all the duplicated data.

I have also created another code to delete the duplicated data from the table `LSBU_Staff`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Phone_number ORDER BY Phone_number)
    AS del_dupl_record
    FROM LSBU_Staff
    WHERE Phone_number > 1
    DELETE FROM LSBU_Staff
    WHERE  Phone_number > 1;
```

And it still deletes all the data.

`LSBU_Staff` columns are: `Staff_id`, `LastName`, `FirstName`, `Speciality_type` and `Phone_number`. I chose `Phone_number` as its identification.

Comment: Please do not SHOUT, not even in the title. Never forget to add your runtime to questions posted here (in this case [tag:sql-server]). You can use back-ticks around variable names to format them in MarkDown.

Comment: Apologies, I did not know. Thank you.

Comment: A link was posted [to mssqltips.com](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4486/find-and-remove-duplicate-rows-from-a-sql-server-table/). The answer was deleted as it did not explain the solution provided therein. I'm just posting it as a *possible* reference instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Not super elegant and can be cleaned up but should do the trick. This will keep the first of the group. If you prefer to keep the last change to "l2.Staff_id > l1.Staff_id"

--

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LSBU_Staff

CREATE TABLE LSBU_Staff
( Staff_id          INT IDENTITY(1,1)
, LastName          VARCHAR(32)
, FirstName         VARCHAR(32)
, Speciality_type   VARCHAR(32)
, Phone_number      VARCHAR(32)
)

INSERT INTO LSBU_Staff (LastName, FirstName, Speciality_type, Phone_number)
VALUES
  ('Stilskin', 'Rumple', 'dancer'   , '305-305-3050')
, ('Lamb', 'Mary', 'shepherd'       , '305-123-4567')
, ('Lamb', 'Aurthur', 'shepherd'    , '305-123-4567')
, ('Fenokee', 'Okee', 'swimmer'     , '305-305-3051')

SELECT * FROM LSBU_Staff

DELETE LSBU_Staff 
WHERE Staff_id IN  
(
    SELECT Staff_id 
    FROM LSBU_Staff l1 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LSBU_Staff l2 WHERE l2.Phone_number = l1.Phone_number 
                                                AND l2.Staff_id < l1.Staff_id)
)

SELECT * FROM LSBU_Staff

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LSBU_Staff
```

Comment: If you can, Juliette, please mar as answer then. Glad it worked!

Comment: I did not know that I could mark your entry as answer! Done.